# What will happen if I remove lxqt for lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

Hey guys I was curious on what will happen if I remove lxqt from lubuntu ? What apps will go away and how will my default desktop look . I am not planning on doing it but just curious . Sorry if this feels stupid

Comment: You can type `sudo apt remove -s lxqt` in a terminal to see the list of programs that would be removed. The s option means that nothing will actually happen.

Comment: I don't want to this but I am newbie to Linux so I was just curious

Comment: You know what they say: curiosity kills the cat! This would not be a good thing to do to your system if you are new to Linux.  If I've sufficiently answered your question below, you can click the checkmark to accept the answer.

Comment: You can look up package details and actually see the effects - I can't provide a link as I don't know your actual release, and the results will differ for each release (*differences may be small, but they still differ*), eg. for `lubuntu-desktop` all *depends* will be removed as well UNLESS you have another program that also depends on them (then they won't be cleaned up but remain on your system where currently most will be auto-installed because of your Lubuntu desktop use)..  https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/lubuntu-desktop  Each requirement can cause it's own removal of packages etc

Comment: I was going to write an answer & follow thru - on my own primary desktop the effect appears minimal (a package is removed); but a *live* system I booted doesn't even have the package installed, likewise a recent QA-test install doesn't have it... They were *impish* but your results may vary as you're likely not asking about *impish* (the current development release).  Release matters (no effect for *impish* though!  an error if a recent install; package removed if older release upgraded which is why package exists on my primary box).  If you want to test it, use a 2nd box like me or VM

Comment: I can explore for you if it's a *focal* or *impish* release you're asking about (you'll be off-topic if *impish* though) as I have QA-test installs of those I'll happily destroy (as they get re-installed anyway next QA-test); the *focal* work is for upcoming 20.04.3 releases; *impish* of course the 21.10 release. I'd suggest creating a VM & installing Lubuntu & doing it yourself.. You'll learn more that way; You can use links like the `lubuntu-desktop` one I used in prior comment to see why if browser is easier than reading CLI/command enquiries. Results though vary on release

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer .

Comment: Enjoy your learning :)  If you create VMs or use a second box, you learn heaps by trying it out & seeing first hand the results... Then you can try and fix the *mess* made (esp. if a mess is created) which teaches heaps.  The packages.ubuntu.com (or CLI commands (I likely did some `apt-cache rdepends` queries) allow you to predict what should happen (I'd suggest predicting first), then you can see if happens as predicted (what I'd have done), then re-explore the results if you were wrong (it happens, we miss things as queries can be spread over multiple pages). I find the *fixing* teaches most

Comment: I might try doing this because as it is I am upgrading to lubuntu  21 I will remember to post the result here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LXQt is the desktop environment for Lubuntu so if you remove it, you will lose your desktop environment and most of your software.

Comment: What do you mean? It is perfectly acceptable to use another desktop environment. You will not lose your software, just the lxqt stuff.

Comment: I was only contesting the part where you wrote "you will lose...most of your software". I don't consider any of that to be "my" software, that is just stuff that came pre-installed that I personally don't use at all. I thought you made it sound like uninstalling lxqt would destroy software OP installed, which isn't true. But yes, you answered the question appropriately and I concede this is a mostly pointless quibble.